# Help me visualize the integral here in this Fourier Transform Operation

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Define a signal $($function$)$ :
$$
x(t):=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $|t|>1$}\\
\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}&\text{if $-1\leq t\leq 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
I wish to compute its Fourier transform in a rather $($smart$)$ efficient way that involves two special property of the Fourier transform that are :
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}g(t)\;\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}\;j\omega X(j\omega)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\int_{-\infty}^{t}g(\tau)\;\text{d}\tau\;\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}\; \frac{1}{j\omega}X(j\omega)+\pi X(0)\delta(j\omega)
$$
Note that the Fourier transform definition that I am using is :
$$
X(j\omega)=\mathcal{F}\{x\}(t):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\;\text{d}t
$$

---

**[Solution]** :

We first use the first special property by computing :
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}x(t)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left[\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}\right]=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Let $y(t):=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}x(t)$, we shall plot the graphs of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$
[image]

The book now uses the second property by writing :
$$
\boxed{x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}y(\tau)\;\text{d}\tau-\color{red}{u\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}
$$
I have two questions :

> $(1)$ : How can I visualize the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{t}g(\tau)\;\text{d}\tau$ for any $g(t)$ to understand what this integral is telling me?

> $(2)$ : Where did the unit-step function colored in red came from? Note that the unit step function is defined as :
> $$
> u(t):=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $t\geq0$}\\0&\text{if otherwise}\end{cases}
> $$

---

If these two questions are answered or clarified I would be happy to complete the problem in my book Signals & Systems by A.V. Oppenheim.

Comment: Your definition of $x(t)$ seems to be wrong. $x(t)$ should be vanishing  for  $\vert t \vert \gt 0$.

Comment: Will fix it now thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that
$$x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t y(\tau) \ d\tau$$ for all $t \le 1$ is pretty clear.

The issue is that for $t \ge 1$ the formula is no more valid as for $t \ge 1$, you have
$$\int_{-\infty}^t y(\tau) \ d\tau= 1$$ while $x(t)=0$.

You need to subtract the shifted unit function to get the valid identity

$$x(t) =\int_{-\infty}^t y(\tau) \ d\tau-u(t-1)$$

**I don’t understand why your book is using $u(t-1/2)$. It seems wrong to me.**

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I have modified the question as you pointed out $x(t)=0$ when in fact $|t|>1$.

Comment: I also am not able to clearly imagine the integral having a bound from $-\infty$ to $t$ how would this transform a square to a triangle?

Comment: What is the integral of a constant map?

Comment: Ah so the integral of a constant should give here $\frac{1}{2}t$ but are you sure its integral of $y(t)$ and not $y(\tau)d\tau$? So can we rewrite integral from $-1$ to $1$?

Comment: You’re right. Better that I use $\tau$ instead of $t$ in the integral as $t$ also appears as a free variable.

Comment: I think I understood everything just one last question, why did we subtract the integral by the unit step function knowing that after $t\geq1, x(t)=y(t)=0$?

Comment: Because for $t \ge 1$ you have $\int_{-\infty}^t y(t) \ dt=1$ while $x(t)=0$.

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you very much!!!